# ¿Cómo separar un string en c#

Tags: c#, .net

Realmente lo que quiero hacer es esto:
Ejemplo:
tengo inicialmente este string: "perroANDgato".
entonces lo que quiero optener es esto:
"perro AND gato"

quisiera saber si existen funcones en .Net que posibiliten hacer esto. gracias

Comment: .net tiene funciones de todo tipo, es uno de los frameworks más completos que hay :D

Comment: falta que expliques cual es la lógica de separación que buscas.  Formas de separar un string abundan, pero tal vez no de la forma como buscas.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer? ¿ insertar espacios ? Si hay un insert ¿Hacer un replace de 'AND' con un ' AND ' (con espacio a la izquierda y a la derecha)? también existe.Pones un ejemplo pero no queda muy claro el objetivo.

Comment: si man,, realmente lo que quisiera es insertar espacios a la derecha e izquierda de AND....el problema es que estoy utilizando un componente .js de querys(consultas) que me retorna una consulta SQL. esa consulta q devuelve tiene todos los caracteres juntos y lo que quiero es separarlos despues del AND..

Answer (score 2):

puedes utilizar replace para lo que quieres:

```
        string str1 = "perroANDgato";
        string str2 = str1.Replace("AND", " AND "); //Resultado: "perro AND gato"
```

pero para que esto te funcione debes conocer la palabra o caracter que estes utilizando como separador.

Comment: perfecto man...el problema e que soy nuevo en .net...muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Bueno hay formas de separar un string por un caracter especifico, te puede servir de algo, abajo te dejo un ejemplo

```
string cadena= "UNO, DOS, TRES, CUATRO, CINCO";
string [] separadas;
separadas=cadena.Split(',');
```

de esta forma el vector "separadas" se llena con 5 strings, ya que el split separada en donde encuentre una coma ","

luego puedes acceder a los datos de la siguiente forma

```
separadas[0]
separadas[1]
```

y asi con el resto